# Svg Filter vs CSS Filter - Blur Performance Differences

Tags: css, svg, filter

There are differences in performance between the SVG filter and the CSS Filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm somehow i shouldn't think the performance would be much of an issue CSS filters are in a way based off SVG filters.

However in terms of critical path, if you embed your svg's (including the filters) i would think they might have better performance because the filters should be parsed with the DOM instead of having a css pointer attached and then rendered after the css is parsed.

If you use sprites however the performance would be pretty much the same.